# Android Studio Git Tool shows wrong file types

Tags: android, git, android-studio

After updating Android Studio to version 4.1, Git Tool now shows all my kotlin and xml files as C++ files.

I have attached a screenshot of the same.

Any idea how to fix this or is it a bug in new version??

[image]

Comment: Yup, it seems broken. Shouldn't be intentional, though couldn't find in know issues - https://developer.android.com/studio/known-issues

Comment: Still relevant in 4.1.1.
Reinstall did not help.

Comment: Another thing: this is also present (along with incorrect icon in taskbar on Win10) with beta and canary versions, so it looks like the issue is related to either some computer setting or maybe even plugin. Which plugins are you using @AnoopM?